# Looping through numbers between two numbers

Tags: excel, vba

I want to do a count for each set of numbers between two numbers in column A (so count the number of 1's, then the number of 2's etc). Essentially what I'm trying to do (although I know this is wrong) is:

```
Dim rangeNo As integer
Dim countNo as integer
Dim top as integer
Dim lastRow as integer

top = 10

rangeNo = 1

lastRow = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For each rangeNo between 1 and top
countNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)), rangeNo)
msgbox (countNo)
rangeNo = rangeNo + 1
Next
```

Its mostly the loop I need help with. I don't know how I can loop between two numbers? Unless i'm doing it totally wrong?

Comment: `For rangeNo = 1 To Top` and then remove your increment `rangeNo = rangeNo + 1`

Comment: look into a normal `For` loop not a `For Each` loop

Comment: The question and the goal of the answer you seek, might be getting lost in the example code. Can you edit the question to put a data source and result example? It sounds like you are trying to make a histogram.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to use the functionality of a [`For...Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/fornext-statement) loop in a [`For Each...Next`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement) loop. Although very similar, the first will loop through a number range whereas the second will loop through an array or collection.

Try:

```
For rangeNo = 1 to top
    countNo = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRow, 1)), rangeNo)
    msgbox (countNo)
Next
```

Notice you don't need to increment `rangeNo` - As you are assigning it's value in the loop, you don't need to do so earlier in your code either.